# SSL related "undefined reference" on libssh2 and libcurl libs when compiling C on OpenSUSE

Tags: ssh, opensuse, c, curl, openssl

I been trying to compile a C software but I'm getting 'undefined reference' over SSL libraries I think. The libraries it mentions are there, actually I compiled them all again: zlib + openssl + openssh. Error persist.

OS openSUSE Leap 42.1.

gcc (SUSE Linux) 4.8.5

GNU Make 4.0

The error when compiling (make -j4):

```
/usr/lib64/libssh2.so.1: undefined reference to `EVP_aes_128_ctr'
/usr/lib64/libssh2.so.1: undefined reference to `EVP_aes_256_ctr'
/usr/local/lib64/libcurl.so: undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_set_srp_username' 
/usr/lib64/libssh2.so.1: undefined reference to `EVP_aes_192_ctr' 
/usr/local/lib64/libcurl.so: undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_set_srp_password' 
/usr/local/lib64/libcurl.so: undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_set_next_proto_select_cb' 
/usr/local/lib64/libcurl.so: undefined reference to `ERR_remove_thread_state' 
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**Libraries dependency info:**

ldd /usr/lib64/libssh2.so.1

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fffcf745000)
libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0x00007fde9b18f000)
libz.so.1 => /usr/local/lib/libz.so.1 (0x00007fde9af75000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007fde9abcd000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fde9a9c9000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000556ace037000)
```

ldd /usr/local/lib64/libcurl.so

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffecd319000)
libssh2.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libssh2.so.1 (0x00007f3e4760e000)
libssl.so.1.0.0 => /lib64/libssl.so.1.0.0 (0x00007f3e473a6000)
libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0x00007f3e46fb1000)
liblber-2.4.so.2 => /usr/lib64/liblber-2.4.so.2 (0x00007f3e46da2000)
libldap-2.4.so.2 => /usr/lib64/libldap-2.4.so.2 (0x00007f3e46b56000)
libz.so.1 => /usr/local/lib/libz.so.1 (0x00007f3e4693c000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f3e46594000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f3e46390000)
libresolv.so.2 => /lib64/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007f3e46178000)
libsasl2.so.3 => /usr/lib64/libsasl2.so.3 (0x00007f3e45f5b000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000055e1d1abf000)
```

Is there a missing dependency? Thanks.

Comment: Very closely related: [compiling curl with openssl giving wrong openssl version](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/318139/56041). Your question wants to build {OpenSSL,cURL,OpenSSH}. The cited question builds {OpenSSL,ngHTTP,cURL}. Slightly different components, but the same issues and same fixes. In fact, the cited even verifies the result with LDD to show the process succeeded.

Answer (score 2):

The error messages are near the end; the beginning is not shown.

The `ldd` does not show the pathnames used for *linking* new programs.  It only shows pathnames used for *running* existing programs.  You might be missing the development package for OpenSSL, which would include symbolic links for names *ending* with ".so" (which would point to the versioned library names that you show in the `ldd` output).

For example, on my OpenSuSE 13, I have `libopenssl-devel-1.0.1k-11.87.1.x86_64` which contains the symbolic links

```
/usr/lib64/libcrypto.so
/usr/lib64/libssl.so
```

Also, `ldd` shows this:

```
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc0d09f000)
    libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0x00007f63ae4f3000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00007f63ae2dd000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f63adf2f000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f63add2b000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f63aeb0a000)
```

which has `libz` installed in the system, rather than built into `/usr/local/lib`, e.g., from `libz1-1.2.8-3.1.2.x86_64` (why you compiled this library is unclear, since it was already a dependency of the `libssh2.so` which is in your system area).

Usually `ldd` will mark libraries which cannot be found.  Your substitute `libz.so` may be a problem, e.g., if it is not the same model as the file it replaced.  You could compare that using the `file` utility.  Also, you can get more information about the actual libraries used for linking using the verbose option `-v` (in case it attempts to use libraries which happen to have the same names as the dependencies shown by `ldd`).

Comment: Hi Thomas, I have openssl-devel (64 and 32) installed. Those symbolic links also exist. 

'libopenssl-devel' is already installed.
'libopenssl-devel-32bit' is already installed.

Comment: Although no previous warning or error showed up before the first undefined reference.

Comment: I compiled libz when compiled openssl and openssh, I have uninstalled that version and installed libz1-1.2.8 package , it installed it again on /lib64/ not in /usr/local/lib64/ I have copied the libz to that location and it still does not work. I'm pasting ldd -v here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f4c0afa034a039d16738c810119d5c80