# compiling curl with openssl giving wrong openssl version

Tags: centos, curl, openssl

I have found various answers on this, but I can't get anything that works for me. I am trying to compile curl with nghttp2 on my CentOS server.

I have compiled it all ok, but my problem is that `curl -V` is showing the wrong openssl version:

```
curl 7.51.0-DEV (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.51.0-DEV
OpenSSL/1.0.1e zlib/1.2.3 nghttp2/1.16.0-DEV
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps pop3 pop3s
rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz HTTP2 UnixSockets
```

When I do `openssl version`, it reports:

```
OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016
```

Can anyone help me to fix this please (I am out of my comfort zone here!)? From what I understand, http2 is not working correctly because openssl needs to be 1.0.2.

Thanks

**EDIT**

I have tried changing my configure to this:

```
./configure  --with-nghttp2=/usr/local --with-ssl=/var/tmp/openssl-1.0.2h
 CPPFLAGS="-I/var/tmp/openssl-1.0.2h/include/openssl" 
 LDFLAGS="-L/var/tmp/openssl-1.0.2h"
```

But now the configure doesn't complete:

```
error: one or more libs available at link-time are not available run-time. 
Libs used at link-time: -lnghttp2   -lssl -lcrypto -lz -lrt
```

The issue is definitely with the openssl linking, as I can configure ok using `--without-ssl`. I suppose, my paths must be wrong - but I am not sure what they should be pointing to?

Comment: I guess it's statically linked so the source package on the machine where you compiled it on is what matters (I think).

Comment: Thanks for you response, but how do I link to the correct one?

Comment: How did you configure OpenSSL?  Also, usually you want to set `CFLAGS` in addition to `CPPFLAGS`. `CPPFLAGS` is the C preprocessor, and it often is not added to `CFLAGS` and `CXXFLAGS`. I believe include directory should be `-I/var/tmp/openssl-1.0.2h/include` (omit the trailing `openssl`). When you configure OpenSSL, [add an RPATH](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation): `./Configure linux-x86_64 -Wl,-rpath,/var/tmp/openssl-1.0.2h/lib`. Do you really run OpenSSL form `/var/tmp`?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I did manage to get this working a couple of weeks ago - pretty much how you described here except I installed openssl in  /usr/local/ssl instead of /var/tmp!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the trick here is you need to get all three components (OpenSSL, ngHTTP and cURL) to use the freshly built OpenSSL. The easiest way is to use an RPATH, and its the `-Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib` shown blow.

***Build OpenSSL***

OpenSSL does not honor `CFLAGS`, so you need to add `-Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib` to your configure line. It explains flags like `ec_nistp_64_gcc_128`.

Also see [Compilation and Installation](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation) on the OpenSSL wiki.

```
$ wget https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.1.0b.tar.gz
$ tar xzf openssl-1.1.0b.tar.gz

$ cd openssl-1.1.0b
$ ./Configure linux-x86_64 shared no-ssl2 no-ssl3 no-comp enable-ec_nistp_64_gcc_128 -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib
Configuring OpenSSL version 1.1.0b (0x0x1010002fL)
***** Deprecated options: no-ssl2
...
SIXTY_FOUR_BIT_LONG mode
Configured for linux-x86_64.

$ make -j 4
...
$ sudo make install
...

$ /usr/local/bin/openssl version
OpenSSL 1.1.0b  26 Sep 2016

$ ldd /usr/local/bin/openssl 
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffcd27e0000)
    libssl.so.1.1 => /usr/local/lib/libssl.so.1.1 (0x00007fe8f8740000)
    libcrypto.so.1.1 => /usr/local/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1 (0x00007fe8f8294000)
    ...
```

***CFLAGS and CXXFLAGS***

Now that a new OpenSSL is available, you need the rest of the components to use it. The minor wrinkle ngHTTP uses both `gcc` and `g++`, so you ned to tune both `CFLAGS` and `CXXFLAGS`.

Personally, I don't mess with `CPPFLAGS`, which is flags to the C preprocessor. Its the compiler driver's job to pass them down to the preprocessor when required.

```
$ export CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/include/ -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib -lssl -lcrypto"
$ export CXXFLAGS="-I/usr/local/include/ -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib -lssl -lcrypto"
```

***Build nghttp2***

The special item here is setting both `CFLAGS` and `CXXFLAGS`.

```
$ wget https://github.com/nghttp2/nghttp2/releases/download/v1.16.0/nghttp2-1.16.0.tar.gz
$ tar xzf nghttp2-1.16.0.tar.gz
$ cd nghttp2-1.16.0

$ CFLAGS="$CFLAGS" CXXFLAGS="$CXXFLAGS" ./configure
...
    Compiler:
      C compiler:     gcc
      CFLAGS:         -I/usr/local/include/ -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib -lssl -lcrypto
      LDFLAGS:        
      C++ compiler:   g++
      CXXFLAGS:       -I/usr/local/include/ -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib -lssl -lcrypto
...
    Libs:
      OpenSSL:        yes (CFLAGS='-I/usr/local/include' LIBS='-L/usr/local/lib -lssl -lcrypto')
    ...

$ make -j 4
...
$ sudo make install
...

Libraries have been installed in:
   /usr/local/lib
...
```

***Build cURL***

Nothing really special here. cURL will use the `CFLAGS`, too.

```
$ wget https://curl.haxx.se/download/curl-7.51.0.tar.gz
$ tar xzf curl-7.51.0.tar.gz

$ cd curl-7.51.0
$ ./configure --help | egrep '(ssl|tls|nghttp2)'
  --enable-tls-srp        Enable TLS-SRP authentication
  --disable-tls-srp       Disable TLS-SRP authentication
  --with-winssl           enable Windows native SSL/TLS
  --without-winssl        disable Windows native SSL/TLS
  --with-darwinssl        enable Apple OS native SSL/TLS
  --without-darwinssl     disable Apple OS native SSL/TLS
  --with-ssl=PATH         Where to look for OpenSSL, PATH points to the SSL
                          installation (default: /usr/local/ssl); when
  --without-ssl           disable OpenSSL
  --with-gnutls=PATH      where to look for GnuTLS, PATH points to the
  --without-gnutls        disable GnuTLS detection
  --with-polarssl=PATH    where to look for PolarSSL, PATH points to the
  --without-polarssl      disable PolarSSL detection
  --with-mbedtls=PATH     where to look for mbedTLS, PATH points to the
  --without-mbedtls       disable mbedTLS detection
  --with-cyassl=PATH      where to look for CyaSSL, PATH points to the
  --without-cyassl        disable CyaSSL detection
  --with-axtls=PATH       Where to look for axTLS, PATH points to the axTLS
  --without-axtls         disable axTLS
  --with-nghttp2=PATH     Enable nghttp2 usage
  --without-nghttp2       Disable nghttp2 usage

$ ./configure --with-ssl=/usr/local --with-nghttp2=/usr/local
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
...
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for ar... /usr/bin/ar
configure: using CFLAGS: -I/usr/local/include/ -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib -lssl -lcrypto
...
configure: Configured to build curl/libcurl:

  curl version:     7.51.0
  Host setup:       x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
  Install prefix:   /usr/local
  Compiler:         gcc
  SSL support:      enabled (OpenSSL)
  SSH support:      no      (--with-libssh2)
  zlib support:     no      (--with-zlib)
  GSS-API support:  no      (--with-gssapi)
  TLS-SRP support:  enabled
  resolver:         default (--enable-ares / --enable-threaded-resolver)
  IPv6 support:     enabled
  Unix sockets support: enabled
  IDN support:      no      (--with-{libidn2,winidn})
  Build libcurl:    Shared=yes, Static=yes
  Built-in manual:  enabled
  --libcurl option: enabled (--disable-libcurl-option)
  Verbose errors:   enabled (--disable-verbose)
  SSPI support:     no      (--enable-sspi)
  ca cert bundle:   /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  ca cert path:     no
  ca fallback:      no
  LDAP support:     no      (--enable-ldap / --with-ldap-lib / --with-lber-lib)
  LDAPS support:    no      (--enable-ldaps)
  RTSP support:     enabled
  RTMP support:     no      (--with-librtmp)
  metalink support: no      (--with-libmetalink)
  PSL support:      no      (libpsl not found)
  HTTP2 support:    enabled (nghttp2)
  Protocols:        DICT FILE FTP FTPS GOPHER HTTP HTTPS IMAP IMAPS POP3 POP3S RTSP SMB SMBS SMTP SMTPS TELNET TFTP

$ make -j 4
...
$ sudo make install
...
```

***Verify Libraries***

After all the hoops, verify things. Especially important is the RPATH so you don't have to waste time with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. `-Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib` ensures the path with the proper shared objects are dialed into the executable.

```
$ which curl
/usr/local/bin/curl

$ ldd /usr/local/bin/curl
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffcd0ffd000)
    libcurl.so.4 => /usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4 (0x00007f86ad8a4000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f86ad4c4000)
    libnghttp2.so.14 => /usr/local/lib/libnghttp2.so.14 (0x00007f86ad293000)
    libssl.so.1.1 => /usr/local/lib/libssl.so.1.1 (0x00007f86ad025000)
    libcrypto.so.1.1 => /usr/local/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1 (0x00007f86acb79000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000560d3d474000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f86ac95b000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f86ac757000)
```

Finally:

```
$ /usr/local/bin/curl -V
curl 7.51.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.51.0 OpenSSL/1.1.0b nghttp2/1.16.0
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL TLS-SRP HTTP2 UnixSockets
```

---

You can cleanup with:

```
$ cd ..
$ rm -rf curl-7.51.0* nghttp2-1.16.0* openssl-1.1.0b*
...
```